# loops when user input is wrong and increments when input is right

Tags: java, do-while

Part of my homework is to create a program that asks the user to input item's price that ranges from 1-1000. If the user enters a price not in the range then the program loops back to ask the price for that same item no.(item no. ranges from 1-10). If the input price is within the range then the program increments the item no. and asks the user to enter the price for that item. This is how I did it. However only item 1 behaves correctly. Please advise.Thanks

```
boolean priceinrange = false;       

do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item " + x + ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true; 

    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {

        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item:"+ (x+=1) + ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;

    }   

    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item"+ (x+=1) + ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item" + x +      ":");

    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item " + (x+=1) +  ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item" + x +  ":");
    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item" + (x+=1)+":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item" + x +  ":");
    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item" + (x+=1)+ ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item  :");
    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item" + (x+=1) + ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item  :");
    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item" + (x+=1)+ ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item  :");
    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item" + (x+=1) +":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item  :");
    }
    while (!priceinrange);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of item" +(x+=1)+ ":");
        price = kb.nextDouble();
        if (price>1 && price<1000)
            priceinrange= true;
        else
            System.out.println ("Please enter the price of item  :");
    }

    while (!priceinrange);
```

Comment: Seems to work okay for me...

Comment: Re title. looping and iterating mean the same thing

Comment: You could reduce the complexity by moving the `do-while` for the prompt to a method which you could call.  Then you could us a simple `for-loop` to prompt for as many items as you wanted...

Comment: Is the 1-1000 range inclusive or exclusive?  You condition is current exclusive (2-999)

Comment: Re question text: "the program iterates the item no." I trust you mean increments the item no.  As in, it adds 1 to whatever the item number is. 0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 2.  That's incrementing.  Mind editing the question please?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I meant increment not iterate. thanks

Comment: Then please edit the question.  I'll be happy to delete my snarky comment once you do.

Comment: I don't think your answer is what expected from this homework. What if you had 1000 items? Would you multiply the same code 1000 times?

Comment: Thanks for correcting the title.  How about correcting the body of the question?  And Roman is right (well almost). copy and paste only seems like it's helping you.  It's really not.  Duplicating code is a bad thing.  Not because 1000 might be needed.  Even 2 is bad.  Because now when you find a problem or decide to make a change you have to fix it in more then one place.  What you need is to use your loops better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete all of the copy and paste code.  The extra code only makes this harder.

The real trick is to loop when input is wrong AND when it's right.  You only stop looping when you've read in 10 valid prices.  You don't care how many times it ends up looping.  You care that you have your 10 prices.

If you think of it like that then only one loop is needed for this.  A `do while (x <= 10)` and a `if (price > 1 && price < 1000) { x += 1;}` will do you a world of good.

You should be able to solve this in fewer than 25 lines of code.  I solved it without using a `priceinrange` boolean at all.

If this isn't enough of a hint let me know.

Comment: I did this and I was able to solve this part in less than 20 lines using the loops effectively. Big help! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `priceinrange` back to false before each `do { } while()`. Otherwise it's still `true` (from "before") even when you enter an invalid price.

The other approach would be to always set it: `priceinrange = (price > 1 && price < 1000)` instead of just setting `priceinrange` to `true` when the condition is met.

Comment: While it is certainly possible to solve this with 10 loops is that really something that should be encouraged?

Comment: Nope, but the actual coding error I've pointed out is the simple logic error that answers the original question. Sure there are other problems in the code that I haven't addressed.